# string calculator - needs to add 2 strings using real numbers I am using 2 for loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to create a program that can take two inputs that are strings convert them to real numbers and add them together. Example an input of "four" and "five" should return 9.

I have added some console.log statements to get values from my variables but I see nothing in my console.  Any help would be appreciated, or perhaps better ways to do this.  I am attempting to do it through iterating through an array, I am just learning javascript.

```
var stringDict = [ ["zero", 0], ['one', 1], ['two', 2], ['three', 3], ['four', 4], ['five', 5], ['six', 6], ['seven', 7], ['eight', 8], ['nine', 9], ['ten', 10]
]


function plus(A, B){
    for (var i = 0; i <= stringDict.length; i++ ) {
        if (A == stringDict[i][0] ) {
            var firstNumber = stringDict[i][1];
            break;
        }
    }
    for (var j = 0; j <= stringDict.length; j++ ) {
        if (A == stringdict[j][0] ) {
            var secondNumber = stringDict[j][1];
            break;
        }
    }
    return firstNumber + secondNumber;
    console.log(firstNumber);
    console.log(secondNumber);
console.log(plus ("one", "three"));
}
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This modified version works.

```
<script>

var stringDict = [ ["zero", 0], ['one', 1], ['two', 2], ['three', 3], ['four', 4], ['five', 5], ['six', 6], ['seven', 7], ['eight', 8], ['nine', 9], ['ten', 10]];

function plus(A, B){
    for (var i = 0; i <= stringDict.length; i++ ) {
        if (A == stringDict[i][0] ) {
            var firstNumber = stringDict[i][1];
            break;
        }
    }
    for (var j = 0; j <= stringDict.length; j++ ) {
        if (B == stringDict[j][0] ) {
            var secondNumber = stringDict[j][1];
            break;
        }
    }
    console.log(firstNumber);
    console.log(secondNumber);

    return firstNumber + secondNumber;
}

console.log(plus ("one", "three"));

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you convert your dictionary to an object instead of array you can get rid of all the looping and greatly simplify this

```
var stringDict = { "zero": 0, 'one': 1, 'two': 2,'three': 3, 'four': 4, 'five': 5,'six': 6,'seven': 7,'eight': 8,'nine': 9,'ten': 10}

function plus(A, B){
    /* should do some validation here first */
    return stringDict[A] + stringDict[B];
}
```